# Using Amadeus flight search API, how does my users search for flight when they don't have location code

Tags: javascript, arrays, amadeus

I am using amadeus flight search API, built the endpoint with PHP and tested on postman, working perfectly now i am worried about how my users will use the frontend to search for flight, do they have to know the city codes to be able to search for flights? I want a situation whereby they just entered the names of the cities in the form from my frontend and they get to search for flights not entering city codes

Comment: You could just create some type of conversion function so that when the users chooses a city in the frontend it's automatically converted to a city code, which you can then send to the api.

Comment: @IvanBacher how do i get all city codes

Comment: I guess i will go with this your suggestion, after thinking about it, i felt this will solve the problem, getting JSON data that has list of locations and cities along with IATA codes and then using filter to filter through as users are entering their input data

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks everyone for the contribution, i am really grateful, though i discovered getting list of JSON data of IATA codes, cities, and countries in my frontend application and then using javascript filter to search through responding to the onChange event handler from the user's form will solve the problem, once again i appreciate everyone contributions, i am really grateful

Answer (score 1):

All the airport and city codes are based on IATA standard.
Amadeus provides also another API to get this information : [Airport and city search API](https://developers.amadeus.com/self-service/category/air/api-doc/airport-and-city-search). you can integrate this so that your user can type a keyword for your application to get the corresponding codes.

Comment: Thanks for this, I am really grateful, though i already figure out a way i could handle the situation, once again thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can also use the City Search to get nearest Airport to a destination (may be a city with no airport). Use the include parameter to get AIRPORTS in the result.

Comment: Please provide a code segment or link to some documentation that could help people understand how to use this. Learn more about great answers [in the help center](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer)